# Wget download after POST, make it wait?

Tags: bash, wget

I am working on bash script in which I use Wget to supply POST data, and Wget is supposed to make POST request on specific page, and that page is supposed to return file for download.The problem is that, after making request, that page returns file after few seconds, not immediately so Wget only downloads html page, and don't wait for that file to be returned.Is there any option to make this work - make post request and wait a few seconds for a file to be returned from remote server ?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an example of how you're using wget. good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If your only problem is that you need more time you can use the sleep command.

You can get more information about it here: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/timedate.html

Hope that helped!

Comment: Well not exactly, I need wget to wait for file to be returned, and that happens after html is returned.However, wget exists after it gets that html, for all it knows something is downloaded and thats the problem.

Comment: Could you post the part of your code where you use wget, I might be able to help more if I can see what exactly you're trying to accomplish